# Why is the windows 7 shortcut for screen capture not working?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, screenshot

**This was resolved by the first commenter**

Usually I can use the Windows+S shortcut to take a screenshot, but it has recently stopped working.  Restarting my computer did nothing.  I understand it is rather difficult to modify shortcuts like this one, so I don't see how I could have done it by accident.  What is going on?

All other shortcuts are working as far as I can tell

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps you can try going to OneNote, `Tools > Options > Other` and change the notification in taskbar

Comment: wow, that did it! I guess it stopped working when I removed that icon from the taskbar; I just didn't think anything of it and don't use the shortcut enough to realize the connection.  Who knew? Thanks

Comment: On the left to my answer, as you move your cursor around that area, you can see a tick. Simply just click that. Welcome to StackExchange and hope you'll stay.

Comment: @elwc glad to see somebody not running off newusers for not reading the faq!

Comment: Even simpler - all it took for me was to just go in and open OneNote, which I hadn't done for a long time.  After re-entering some credentials, and closing OneNote I saw that this Windows+S copy feature worked again.

Answer (score 2):

In OneNote2010 - I followed this

Open OneNote -> Insert -> "Screen Clipping"  from Images

Then close OneNote and start using Windows+S shortcut for your screen prints

Comment: This method worked best since my OneNote does not have a "Tools" button.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open OneNote -> Insert -> "Screen Clipping" from Images
2. Right click on "Screen Clipping" select add to toolbar option.
3. Then close OneNote and start using Windows+S shortcut for your screen prints